# Bootstrap card-header doesn't work

Tags: laravel, frameworks, bootstrap-4

I'm using Laravel 5.5 and looking at the Bootstrap's 4 documentation i found that the card components works just fine for the things i want to do. Either way, there is an error while i'm trying to create a basic card model:

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="row col-md">
          <div class="card">
               <div class="card-header">
                    Companies
               </div>
               <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                 <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
                 <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
                 <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
                 <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
                 <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
               </ul>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

That piece of code should look fine but the "card-header" does not... Any ideas ?

PD: Not even the basic example (provided by the docs) works for me...

[screen example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VShL4.png)

Answer (score 0):

In the bootstrap code it says "Card headers can be styled by adding .card-header to  elements."

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/

Change your div to be a h3 or a h* element and it should work.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row col-md">
              <div class="card">
                   <h2 class="card-header">
                        Companies
                   </h2>
                   <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                     <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
                     <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
                     <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
                     <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
                     <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
                   </ul>
              </div>
         </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: That just increases the header's text size. Nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this is breaking your layout, but you should not put *row* and *col* classes on one container. From [bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#how-it-works):

> In a grid layout, content must be placed within columns and only
>   columns may be immediate children of rows

Check the snippet with a working example.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="card" style="margin: 50px">
        <div class="card-header">
          Companies
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
          <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```